# How can I access Github user ID from Python having only email or name?

Tags: python, github

I need to get Github user ids by their names or emails. How can I do that?

Thanks :)

I was trying to use pygithub but that doesnt seem to help much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Github user search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search#search-users)

`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=EnterEmailHere`